# как удалить все вхождения слова из строки?

Tags: delphi

Программа удаляет ключевое слово, введенное в edit (к примеру ввожу слово 2018) и все что после ключевого слова.

То есть:
`Test1 2018 Test2 2018 Test3 2018` - После обработки получаю результат: `Test1`

А нужно чтобы:
`Test1 2018 Test2 2018 Test3 2018` - После обработки получить результат: `Test1 Test2 Test3`

То есть удалить только ключевое слова. Как можно исправить ?

```
var
    s:string;
    p:Word;
    toDelete: TStringList;
    iDelete: integer;

    begin
    toDelete := TStringList.Create;
      toDelete.Add(edit1.Text);

    ................................
    Вот тут нужна помощь
    .................................
    for iDelete := 0 to toDelete.Count - 1 do begin
            repeat
              p := Pos(toDelete[iDelete], s);
              if p <> 0 then
                Delete(s, p, p + Length(toDelete[iDelete]) - 1);
            until p = 0;
    .................................
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пардон, Татьяна, это я Вам тогда неправильно написал. Последний параметр - количество символов для удаления.

```
Delete(s, p, Length(toDelete[iDelete]));
```

Другой вариант. Вместо `repeat/until`

```
s := StringReplace(s, toDelete[iDelete], '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
```

Comment: Igor, Как всегда благодарна. Только еще один вопрос. После удаления получается двойной отступ между словами. То есть Test1 -тут-  Test2  -тут- Test3. Как его убрать?.

Comment: `s := StringReplace(s, '  ', ' ', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);` Второй параметр - два пробела, третий параметр - один пробел.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

В две строчки удаляется вот так:

```
s := StringReplace(s, toDelete[iDelete] + ' ', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
s := StringReplace(s, ' ' + toDelete[iDelete], '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
```

То есть мы заменяем все `2018` на пусто, и все `2018` на пусто. Т.о. у нас не будет лишних пробелов.

Альтернативно можно сделать вот так - убрать слово и заменить все двойные пробелы на одинарные:

```
s := StringReplace(s, toDelete[iDelete], '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
s := StringReplace(s, '  ', ' ', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
```

Comment: Тоже нужный совет. Благодарна Вам, Kromster.